# How to show value zero in Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 even when value is nothing in mysql

Tags: mysql

I would like to show Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 although the value is empty or zero...my query is like so

```
Select Coalesce(Quarter(day_date), 0), year(day_date)
from daily
group by year(day_date)
order by year(day_date)
```

but it still exclude the value when Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 have no value or zero

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Consider handling the logic of missing data in application level code

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `cross join` to generate all combinations of years and quarters in the data:

```
Select y.yyyy, q.qq, count(d.day_date)
from (select distinct year(day_date) as yyyy from daily) y cross join
     (select 1 as qq union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4) q left join
     daily d
     on year(d.day_date) = y.yyyy and
        quarter(d.day_date) = q.qq
group by y.yyyy, q.qq
order by y.yyyy, q.qq;
```

Actually, the `left join` is only needed if you actually want to calculate something from the `daily` table, such as the count.

Comment: Not exactly as i want it maybe because the day_date data does not exist at certain period ....for example there is no data exist between 1 Jan to 30 April...therefore Q1 does not include